# How to add a real map as the background to a plot

Tags: python, geopandas

I am trying to add a real map behind my plot in order to show the locations of my datapoints.

But I don't know how to add the real map...

I've tried several ways, like put another png behind the plot.

But it just not right.

Here is what I got.

```
import geopandas as gpd
import tilemapbase

BBox = (df.Longitude.min(), df.Longitude.max(), df.Latitude.min(), df.Latitude.max())
print(BBox)
(3.3990449, 7.042425700000001, 50.8134557, 53.4066264)

tilemapbase.start_logging()
tilemapbase.init(create=True)
extent = tilemapbase.extent_from_frame(NL_shape, buffer = 25)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
plotter = tilemapbase.Plotter(extent, tilemapbase.tiles.build_OSM(), width=1000)
plotter.plot(ax)
ax.set_xlim(BBox[0]-0.2, BBox[1]+0.2)
ax.set_ylim(BBox[2]-0.5, BBox[3]+0.5)
NL_shape.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.3, edgecolor="black", facecolor="white")
stores_shape.plot(ax=ax, alpha = 0.2, color="red", marker='o');
```

I followed the instructions from here: https://rosenfelder.ai/create-maps-with-python/

I used the geopandas to read the boundary of the country(json) and then plot my data.

But I cannot use tilemapbase to download the realmap.

The result is like this:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this problem? Thank you.

The expected image is like this. Basemap should like OpenStreetmap.

[image]

After I used the CONTEXTILY, I had an error.

It showed like this:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Can you show expected image?

Comment: OK, I added it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `contextily` library made for GeoPandas. - https://contextily.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

```py
import contextily as cx

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(10,10))
NL_shape.plot(ax=ax, alpha=0.3, edgecolor="black", facecolor="white")
stores_shape.plot(ax=ax, alpha = 0.2, color="red", marker='o');
cx.add_basemap(ax, crs=NL_shape.crs, source=cx.providers.OpenStreetMap.Mapnik)
```

Comment: I believe it works! But I have an issue in my development environment. I cannot download the contextily package...

Comment: Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.

PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current channels:

  - contextily

Comment: Solving environment: / 
Warning: 2 possible package resolutions (only showing differing packages):
  - anaconda/osx-64::openssl-1.1.1h-haf1e3a3_0
  - defaults/osx-64::openssl-1.1.1h-haf1e3a3done

Comment: `conda config --env --add channels conda-forge` and `conda install contextily -c conda-forge` may help.

Comment: OK. Now I found a way to overcome the problem and install the context. But there is an error: AttributeError: 'AxesImage' object has no property 'source'